# Текст основного тега, без внутренних

Tags: python, парсер, bs4, web-scraping

Как с bs4 вытащить текст именно из основного тега. Вот например после bs4 в принт я получаю такой тег:

```
<td>
<small>Инверторная технология</small>нет
                                                    </td>
```

Как мне из него извлечь именно текст "нет", не затрагивая "Инверторная технология"?
Способ find(text=True) выдает пустую строку. А .text выдает "Инверторная технологиянет" слитный текст.
Вот тег в сайте:
https://prnt.sc/KVC6YUuMEkaQ

Comment: soup.strings или soup.stripped_strings

Comment: спасибо способ подошел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a = "<td><small>Инверторная технология</small>нет                             </td>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(a, 'lxml')
td1, td2 = list(soup.stripped_strings)
print(td2)

# нет
```